# What kind of charts Jira provides out-of-the-box (without any plugins)?

Tags: jira

I'm new to Jira and I want to know what kind of charts, diagrams etc it provides out-of-the-box (without any plugins)?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust a lot of charts to your dashboard already without depending on ad-ons. Too many to mention them, e.g. Burndown-Charts, ProgressCharts...

See Atlassians resources here for adding charts to a page, from there you can read on and find articles related to the different types of charts: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confcloud/jira-chart-macro-724765322.html

Comment: Thank you! The first step is: In the editor choose Insert... Where do I find that editor?